# doubling function

Tags: scheme, racket

Using

```
(define (double fn) (lambda (x) (fn (fn x))))
```

can you explain how

```
((((double double) double) 1+) 0)
```

equals 16?? How does it work using substitution?

Answer (score 1):

The `double` function accepts another function (let's call that function `fn`) as it's argument, then returns a function accepting one arbitrary argument. It passes that argument to `fn`, then passes the result of *that* to `fn`, and that is the result.

For example:

```
> ((double add1) 1)
3
```

It calls `add1` on 1, which returns 2, then it calls `add1` on 2 which gives us the result, 3.

In your example, we pass double to itself, so now we have a procedure which, when given your `1+`, will add 4 to anything we give it (since we have two `double`'s, and each `double` calls two `1+`'s). But then we pass our new procedure *another* `double`, so that we have eight `double`'s (two will be called by all four of the `double`'s we have already created). Each of these eight calls `1+` twice.

So this new procedure will call `1+` twice, eight times, to whatever argument you give it, thus adding 16 to any argument you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it work using substitution?

If you are using Racket, you can use DrRacket's Stepper Tool in the "Intermediate Student with lambda" language to see the exact substitution steps.