# Scheme Substitution Model

Tags: scheme, racket

For the procedure:

```
(define (double fn) (lambda (x) (fn (fn x))))
```

When calling:

```
(((double (double double)) 1+) 0)
```

Is this correct:

```
(double (lambda (x) (double (double x) 1+) 0))
        ((lambda (x) (double^4 x) 1+) 0)
                ((double^4 1+) 0)
                 (16+ 0)
                    16
```

And similarly, when calling:

```
(((((double double) double) double) 1+) 0)
```

Is this correct:

```
(((double double (double double) double) 1+) 0)
  (double (double (lambda (x) (double (double x) 1+) 0)))
    (double (lambda (x) (double^4 1+) 0))
            ((lambda (x) (double^16 x) 1+) 0)
                         ((double^16 1+) 0)
                              (256+ 0)
                                256
```

Comment: What is `1+`, `16+`, `256+`, `double^4` and `double^16`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [doubling function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742866/doubling-function)

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend the stepper in DrRacket. It allows you to show one step at a time. It even allows you to go back.

[image]

First I chose the language "HTDP: Advanced with lambda".
Then I entered this program:

```
(define (double fn) 
  (lambda (x) (fn (fn x))))

(((double (double double)) add1) 0)
```

Finally I clicked the stepper button.